# Python __gettattr__ returning function

Tags: python, codebase

I am currently trying to read python codebase - I picked up the [crayons](https://github.com/kennethreitz/crayons) by Kenneth Reitz as it seems very well written and rather simple, but I am having issues understanding the meaning of the following method ([code ref](https://github.com/kennethreitz/crayons/blob/master/crayons.py#L52)):

```
...
def __getattr__(self, att):
    def func_help(*args, **kwargs):
        result = getattr(self.s, att)(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            is_result_string = isinstance(result, basestring)
        except NameError:
            is_result_string = isinstance(result, str)
        if is_result_string:
            return self._new(result)
        elif isinstance(result, list):
            return [self._new(x) for x in result]
        else:
            return result
    return func_help
...
```

While I have pretty good idea what the magic method `__getattr__` does, I kind of struggle seeing the point of returning the function (or how would I use it for that matter).

Comment: Because the user is expecting a callable - this is used in *method* resolution, and wraps the methods on whatever `self.s` is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe From docs: `This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception.` I suppose it can be used for any attribute - not exclusively callables. Is this based on assumption (fact actually), that python string has only methods and no properties?